# How to give meaningful id names to blocks?

Tags: 7, theming, blocks

Instead of styling with ids/classes such as `block-block-3` which may be deleted and then recreated, how would I go about giving my blocks meaningful names?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/58797/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-use-dynamically-generated-ids-for-theming

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [block class module](http://drupal.org/project/block_class). Block Class allows users to add classes to any block through the block's configuration interface.

Answer (score 3):

You could also do something with [hook_preprocess_block](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/template_preprocess_block/7):

e.g, in template.php

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_block(&$variables){

  // Add class including block-my-subject
  $variables['classes_array'][] = drupal_html_class('block-' . $variables['block']->subject);

  // Add arbitrary class to specific block
  if ($variables['block']->module == 'user' && $variables['block']->delta == 'login') {
    $variables['classes_array'][] = 'my-special-class';
  }

  // Add unique id including block-my-subject
  $variables['block_html_id'] = drupal_html_id('block-' . $variables['block']->subject);

}
```

As a purely theme based solution for a CSS class issue.

Keep in mind, the reason the default class and id are not like that is because the class or id will change if the block subject is changed, breaking any CSS rules there, whereas module name and delta are consistently unique for that block. as per

```
$variables['block_html_id'] = drupal_html_id('block-' . $variables['block']->module . '-' . $variables['block']->delta);
```

Nevertheless, worth mentioning you can add a unique class or id with hook_preprocess_block at the theme layer. No module required.

Comment: Thanks David. That sounds great, but a bit too complicated for a beginner dummy like myself :(