# Change URL to meaningful name when I use hyperlink target

Tags: 7, blocks, uri, navigation

Scenario:

```
<a href="#block-block-1">Book</a>
```

When I click book, it will scroll down to the block and url will be www.example.com/#block-block-1. Is there anyway to change url to something meaningful like www.example.com/#book?

I've tried suggestions from [How to give meaningful id names to blocks?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/58982/how-to-give-meaningful-id-names-to-blocks), but it is not really what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Block Attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_attributes) module will let you add a meaningful `id` attribute to any Drupal block.

> The Block Attributes module allows users to specify additional HTML
>   attributes for blocks, through the block's configuration interface,
>   such as class, id, style, title and more.